# how to pass textbox values to a php page while clicking a link to that page

Tags: html, forms

This is my html code

```
<form id="searchForm">
<input name="search" type="text"/> 

<a href="search.php" id="searchLink"><img src="images/search-btn.jpg"  alt="search-btn" /></a>
</form>
```

How to send this textbox value to search.php page while clicking on the link?

Comment: Doesn't really have anything to do with either PHP or Javascript.

Comment: i thought it may require javascript..

Answer (score 4):

You could give an `action` to your form pointing to the PHP script that you want to be invoked and use an image submit button instead of an anchor:

```
<form id="searchForm" action="search.php" method="post">
    <input name="search" type="text"/> 
    <input type="image" src="images/search-btn.jpg" alt="search-btn" />
</form>
```

Comment: What about a `<button>` element? Also, why does an `input image` submit a form?

Comment: @JaredFarrish i want to use that image rather than a button.. That's why..

Comment: @JaredFarrish, an input type="image" submits the form because that's what the HTML specification states. type="submit" and type="image" both submit the form.

Comment: @arunrc, if this answer helped you solve the problem you were having you might consider marking it as answer by clicking on the tick next to it (unless of course you have further questions on this topic) : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/130891

Comment: @aronrc - You can still use your picture. See: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/RBUCw/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I just found it an odd notion than an `input` of `image` type would be interpreted as a `submit` initializer. Obvious question, I guess, but why else would they have an `image` in an `input`? They wouldn't, I suppose. Nevermind. `:)`

Comment: They have an `image` in an input to allow submitting a form with an image button and sending the `x` and `y` coordinates of where the user clicked on this image to the server.

Comment: The x/y bit is mildly interesting. It's late I guess, brains not quite in gear.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, suppose that you have a large image and based on the coordinates on which the user clicked on this image, take different action on the server when the form is submitted. Like for example a map with countries asking the user to pick a country or something.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Well... That's obviously a case for using a Java `applet` or, if you're sadistic, maybe a Flash program with whizbangs out the whawhoo. For the kids. Practicality, smacticality. `:O :P` After reviewing the MDN page on `<button>`, and it's apparently broad browser support, I don't know why anyone would use `input image`. I had the impression (gotten where, I don't know) that `<button>` was a poorly supported element with freaky gotchas and avoided it, but that appears to be dumb. I added an answer with a `<button>` demo, too.

Answer (score 1):

Note, as an alternative addendum, you can also use the `<button>` element, which allows for more nifty and possibly awesome styling than the clunky `<input>` element.

From the [MDN specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/button#Notes):

> **`<button>` elements are much easier to style than `<input>`  elements.** You
>   can add inner HTML content (think `<em>`, `<strong>` or even `<img>`), and
>   make use of `:after`  and `:before`  pseudo-elements to achieve complex
>   rendering while `<input>` only accepts a text value attribute.

It has several attributes which are `HTML5` only, so be careful to review your attributes's requirement if you're not using that DOCTYPE, as well as the browser vendor compatibility chart on the MDN page. In reality, all the ones you will need in practice for now are already supported by all browsers.

**Demo:**

```
<form id="form" action="search.php">
    <button type="submit" id="button">
        <p><input name="search" type="text"/></p>
        <img src="http://goo.gl/UohAz" alt="search-btn" id="img" />
    </button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/RBUCw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use submit button that will submit form to search.php, there you can get search box value through $_POST[] variable. If you want to show search keyword to the URL, use GET method and access in search.php trough $_GET.

Comment: I know about submit. but i want to use that image rather than a button..Anyway thanks for the help..

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<form id="searchForm" action="search.php" method="post">
    <input name="search" type="text"/> 
    <input type="submit" style="background:images/search-btn.jpg"  />
</form>
```

Comment: But the image is not displaying. It's showing a button with value 'Submit Query'.. Anyway i got the answer from Mr.Darin.. Thanks Rupesh for help...

Answer (score -1):

You can use onClick method inside anchor tag to submit the form. href need to be set to '#'. Also, action of form need to be set to search.php.

```
<form id="searchForm" action="search.php">
  <input name="search" type="text" />
  <a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('searchForm').submit();" id="searchLink"><img src="images/search-btn.jpg"  alt="search-btn" /></a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Kshitij for the help...:) The answer i required had given by Darin..

Comment: down voter plz give your reasons

Comment: @Kshitij I downvoted because I think this is a really bad practice. Submitting a form with an `a` element (when you could simply use `button` or `input`) should not be encouraged. Javascript (and inline event handlers...) is unnecessary here.

Comment: Using input type="image" is definitely a good approach as suggested by Darin above. But I dont think button is a good option here as it unnecessarily adds button effects(i.e. press effect and border) to the image which is not what OP needed. The solution I have provided is just fix of OP's existing code and I dont see this as a bad approach. Ofcourse, you can remove the anchor part and use an image onClick instead, but as i said, the code is just a fix of OP's existing code.